# How can I prioritize 'open with' apps in KDE?

Tags: kde, defaults

When I right click an mkv file in file browser and select 'Open With' I see the list:

- Dragon Player
- VLC Media PLayer

When I double click it, it launches the file in Dragon Player. I'd like to change that so that it launches in VLC Media Player as the default double-click action. Where do I set that?

I looked in Settings > Default Applications, but there is nothing there that seems to apply to this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `right click -> properties -> file type options` and edit, delete, reorder or add the entries, which will appear in the "open with" dialog.
You can access this same dialog via `System Settings -> File associations

Comment: Aha yes, under 'Application Preference Order'. That's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can set default application for every type of file by right-clicking it and "Open with" option. Then choose the application (in your case, VLC) and mark flag "remember application association" then run application.

Comment: I actually did that. That's how I added VLC in the first place, but that doesn't give it priority over the already assigned Dragon Player.